# Grid.MVC when Edit link On Click pass the parameter to ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to pass a parameter from Grid.MVC

Here's my Code:

**Details.cshtml**

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>  
                    {  
                        columns.Add(c => c.CustomerID).Titled("Customer ID").Filterable(true);  
                        columns.Add(c => c.CustomerName).Titled("Customer Name").Filterable(true);  
                        columns.Add()  
                        .Encoded(false)  
                        .Sanitized(false)  
                        .SetWidth(30)  
                        .RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = o.CustomerID }));  

                    }).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true)
```

When i hit the Edit portion of the Grid view i am trying to pass the `o.CustomerID`  into `HomeController` which is  public ActionResult `Edit`(int `ModelCustomID`)

```
 MVC.Grid.Models.Sales_DWEntities salesin = new Models.Sales_DWEntities();
        List<Models.DimCustomer> CustomerList = new List<Models.DimCustomer>();
        public ActionResult Details()
        {
             CustomerList = (from sales in salesin.DimCustomers select sales).ToList();
             return View(CustomerList);
        }
        public ActionResult Edit(int ModelCustomID)
        {
            var custid = (from sale in salesin.DimCustomers where sale.CustomerID == ModelCustomID select sale).FirstOrDefault();


            return View();
        }
```

**Here's the Edit.cshtml**

```
@model MVC.Grid.Models.DimCustomer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";

}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>DimCustomer</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerAltID)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerAltID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerAltID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Gender)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

As my result in `Edit.cshtml` view:
All Fields doesn't have any value return other than `null`

My problem is:

**From:**

```
.RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = o.CustomerID }));
```

then pass the o.CustomerID value

**To** : `Edit(int ModelCustomID)` to the control of `Edit.cshtml`

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int ModelCustomID)
    {
        var custid = (from sale in salesin.DimCustomers where 
sale.CustomerID == ModelCustomID select sale).FirstOrDefault();


        return View();
    }
```

Here's my RouteConfig.cs

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Edit",
        url: "Edit",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Edit" }
    );
```

Any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have problem that your action Edit value of ModelCustomID is null?if yes, I think that you must use `.RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { ModelCustomID = o.CustomerID }));`. I hope that I help you.

Comment: Yes i got a null value to `ModelCustomID  = null`.. Thanks @StanislavMachel i'll try your suggestion.

Comment: @StanislavMachel thanks it is working but all the control of Edit.cshtml is null.

Comment: If you mean "control" as data of inputs, labels and etc, be your model is empty?

Comment: No What i mean is this `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerID)`

Comment: Sorry for delay, but I think that you must pass model to `return View(yourModel);` in Edit action in your controller.

Comment: Yeah I made it already.. i used to choose razor html way to bring back the value again and pass to the controller.